# toggleClass with setInterval for current class (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, setinterval, toggleclass

I have a couple of boxes that have a shadow. I want the shadow to pulse on hover. The code below works but obviously makes *all* shadows to pulsate when I hover any one of them. I've tried to use `this` in the setInterval function in order to apply the pulse effect on a single box only – but that breaks the code all together. What should I do?

```
$( ".pulse_label_shadow" ).hover(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
       $( '.pulse_label_shadow' ).toggleClass("pulse_label_shadow_hover");
    }, 450);
  }
);
```

Or perhaps better and/or easier, how can I add the setInterval while using:

```
$( ".pulse_label_shadow" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass("pulse_label_shadow_hover");
}, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "pulse_label_shadow_hover" );
   }
);
```

The css looks like this, if that makes any difference:

```
.pulse_label_shadow{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.pulse_label_shadow_hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 95px 1px rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 95px 1px rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 95px 1px rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
}
```

And the HTML (for one of the boxes):

```
<div name="NameOfDiv">
    <a class="p1 scale1_toggle scale1_toggle_hide taphover ios_auto_playback floating show_text_on_enter1" rel="nofollow" aria-haspopup="false">
        <div class="indicator_up"><img src="images/indicators/up.png"/></div>
        <div class="pulse_label pulse_label_shadow border_up">
        <span class="ending_arrows">Title</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Edit: Thanks for a lot of great answers with different approaches. I'll select an answer once I've tested them out a bit more.**

Comment: can you add the required HTML?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Absolutely, I've edited my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( ".pulse_label_shadow" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass("pulse_label_shadow_hover");
}, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "pulse_label_shadow_hover" );
   }
);
```

So this should add and remove classes as described, I think your problem is the 'pulse', where you will need to run the **transition** repeatedly. For this we should use an **animation** with 'animation-iteration-count:infinite'.

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {  
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
    }
    100% {  
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 95px 1px rgba(255, 0, 0 ,0.5); 
    }
}


.pulse_label_shadow_hover{ 
    animation: pulse 5s infinite; 
}
```

An example without jQuery to do the hover http://codepen.io/mrbizle/pen/QjEMeO

Comment: Of course! I should have thought of that... Works perfect and is probably the most simple (read: the most efficient) one for me to use right now.

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting all the `.pulse_label_shadow` at once instead of binding `hover` callback for each one. Try using [jQuery `each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), please look at my fiddle:

### Edit

Sorry, I've misunderstood your question, I've solved it here, take a look at my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ahdqnkdy/3/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as far as I can see, I've added the html if that's any help.

Comment: @Lenny sorry, I've posted wrong revision. Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Set the interval and clear it on remove using `clearInterval()`.

```js
var interval;
$(".pulse_label_shadow").hover(function(event) {
  console.log('bsaang');
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    $(event.target).closest(".pulse_label_shadow").toggleClass("pulse_label_shadow_hover");
  }, 450);
}, function(event) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $(event.target).closest(".pulse_label_shadow").removeClass("pulse_label_shadow_hover");
});
```

```css
.pulse_label_shadow{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.pulse_label_shadow_hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 95px 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 95px 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 95px 1px rgba(255, 0, 0 ,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="NameOfDiv">
  <a class="p1 scale1_toggle scale1_toggle_hide taphover ios_auto_playback floating show_text_on_enter1" rel="nofollow" aria-haspopup="false">
    <div class="indicator_up">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ig9P2v1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="pulse_label pulse_label_shadow border_up">
      <span class="ending_arrows">Title</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Got SyntaxError, and I couldn't get it to work after fixing that either. I added the html to the original post as well.

Comment: @Lenny see the updated answer. Changes shadow color for more visibility.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks a lot! I've never used '.closest' before, so thanks for introducing me to this functionality.